# 3-cycle cover decision problem for directed graphs: best known algorithm and maximum size of tractable problems

Tags: algorithms, graphs, np-complete, vertex-cover

I know that the 3-cycle cover decision problem for directed graphs (3-DCC), defined as finding whether a directed graph has a disjoint vertex cycle cover in which every cycle has at least 3 edges, is NP-complete.

Does anyone know what is the actual scaling of the best known algorithm to solve that problem? And, most importantly, what graphs can be tackled with that algorithm?

e.g., I have a graph with 2000 vertices and 2500 edges. Is this solvable? Do I need a supercomputer? What are the limits?

Comment: No idea, but I would try ILP. There is a straightforward formulation: a binary variable per edge, for each vertex a constraint of exactly one in-edge and one out-edge, for each pair of vertices with edges in both directions a constraint that their variables have different values; add an "is covered" variable for each vertex and maximise the sum of these. Even if freely available ILP solvers can't solve it, they will solve the underlying LP which will either (a) already be able to tell you the answer is definitely "no" or (b) suggest useful directions via rounding.

Comment: what is your notion of best? If that means fast for "easy" big instances, Iwould also suggest using ILP solvers but with the twist to start from an unconstraint assignment provlem and then repeat, adding the mutexing constraint for antiparallel arcs as they appear in the solution. If you use pyomo for the ILP formulation then you can easily try out different solvers without having to reformulate your ILP.

Comment: by the way, I am looking for interesting instances of that problem for testing a heuristic.